# Compare minutes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following function:

```
void compareTimes() {
int daysBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
    from = DateTime(from.year, from.month, from.day);
    to = DateTime(to.year, to.month, to.day);
  return (to.difference(from).inDays).round();
}

  final date1 = DateTime.parse("2022-05-27 23:00:00");
  final date2 = DateTime.parse("2022-05-28 23:00:00");
  final difference = daysBetween(date1, date2);
  print(difference);
}
```

With it I can get the DAYS difference between date1 and date2.

But, I would like to get the minutes difference between these dates, example: "2022-05-27 23:00:00" and "2022-05-27 23:10:00", it's 10 minutes difference, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [`Duration`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Duration-class.html)'s property [`inMinutes`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Duration/inMinutes.html):

```dart
void compareTimes() {
  int minutesBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to) =>
      to.difference(from).inMinutes;

  final date1 = DateTime.parse("2022-05-27 23:00:00");
  final date2 = DateTime.parse("2022-05-27 23:10:00");
  final difference = minutesBetween(date1, date2);
  print(difference); // 10
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use inMinutes

```
void compareTimes() {
int daysBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
    from = DateTime(from.year, from.month, from.day);
    to = DateTime(to.year, to.month, to.day);
  return (to.difference(from).inMinutes).round();
}

  final date1 = DateTime.parse("2022-05-27 23:00:00");
  final date2 = DateTime.parse("2022-05-28 23:00:00");
  final difference = daysBetween(date1, date2);
  print(difference);
}
```